# functional equation satisfy some conditions

Tags: functions

> If $f:\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and given that $f(1,1) = 2$ and $f(\alpha+1,\beta) = f(\alpha,\beta)+\alpha$
>
> and $f(\alpha,\beta+1) = f(\alpha,\beta)-\beta\forall \alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{N}$ and $f(a,b) = 2001$. Then
>
> $(1)$ Number of ordered pair of $(a,b)\;\;\;\;\; (2)\;\; \max(a+b)\;\;\;\;\; (3)\;\; \min (a-b)$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Given $f(1,1) = 2$ So $f(2,1) = f(1,1)+1 = 3$ and $f(1,2) = f(1,1)-1 = 1$

similarly $f(2,2)=f(1,2)+1=2$ and $f(2,2)=f(2,1)+1=4$

Now i did not understand how can i solve it, Help required, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint (by telescoping the two recurrences):

$$f(\alpha, \beta) = f(1,1) + \frac{1}{2}\,\alpha\,(\alpha-1) - \frac{1}{2}\,\beta\,(\beta - 1)$$